# Prototyping tool which allows me to dynamically interact with changing numbers?

Tags: tools, prototype, dynamic-ui

I'm trying to prototype a sports related app which has a dependency on the game clock.

1 second will be equal to 1 minute of game time, and I want to prototype to scroll through from 1 to 90. However I'd like to allow the user to be able to make specific interactions during any minute such as leave their seat.

I then want to use that specific minute to update later flows. For example, in this game there are 0.5 passes per minute, if a user leaves their seat at minute 60 the next screen will say congratulations you've watched 30 passes!

I think some simple coding may be involved but not sure if any of the existing prototyping tools (invision, marvel, flinto etc) support this type of functionality?

Worst case scenario I just make it completely the same every time but this way is a bit more fun.

This is for a mobile site/mobile app.

Cheers!

Comment: This isn't really a UX question. You've already decided on the user experience here, now you're looking to build / prototype it. Just because prototyping itself is a UX activity, the recommendation of products or instructions on how to use them are not UX issues I'm afraid.

Comment: It's about the implementation of a UX design. So anything about tools should be removed from this exchange?

Answer (score 1):

[Axure pro](http://www.axure.com) is really good, however it's time consuming because you have to work with conditional logic and then you are only prototyping for specific scenarios.

I would suggest that you be more specific about user stories and acceptance criteria if you are working agile. If not than detailed wireframes coupled with a specification document should be fine.

If you are keen to demo the prototype then I think building  it would be much easier. This doesn't  have to be perfect.

BTW Axure pro allows you to export snippets of code to help with the built.

Hope that helps

**update**

There are a number of Axure pro [tutorials](http://www.axure.com/learn/advanced/variables) that demonstrate how you can carry numbers and variables across pages.

Comment: From experience working with Axure, I tend to hesitate to recommend it as a prototyping tool. The fact that is such a time consuming task to emulate some behaviour can often do more harm than good.

Comment: Thanks guys. I emailed flinto and marvel and they both confirmed this level of functionality does not exist in the current batch of apps at the moment